# Is it possible to have a fragment as popup through navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin, popup, fragment

I want to press an item in a recyclerView (fragment a, master) opening another fragment (fragment b, detail) through Navigation. That fragment (fragment b) have a constraintLayout centered on the screen (containing information on said item), not taking up all the space in the window. The background in fragment b (constraintLayout and frameLayout) is set to background:transparent, not working. I want to see fragment a in the background (preferable maybe through a slight blur), making fragment b as a popup.

I am able to create popup in fragment "a" through new views(layouts) in fragment a. But what's important is to segregate the popup in other files. I dont want the code in fragment b to clutter up the code in fragment a. Fragment a have code dealing with recyclerView, so will fragment b.
I guess that the reason I'm not able to see fragment "a" is that fragment b is not placed on top of fragment "a". Rather, it's replaced in the view.

In iOS it's possible to set similar Navigation and specify that what you want is the destination view to ble placed on top of the "source" view (adding the view on top in the view stack rather that replacing it). Is it some configuration going on in android that can solve my problem?

I have tried some of the configurations in Android Studio considering the "action", but it doesn't look like something I'm looking for, at least I'm not able to produce the desired outcome.

```
val actionMinDetail = MinFragmentDirections.actionToMinDetailFragment(id)
        Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(actionMinDetail)
```

Comment: not sure I understood everything ; https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html

Answer (score 0):

So, after some trial and error I'v ended up with a solution.

@Zack Bvy:
I did try DialogFragment but I wasn't able to use it as a popup. The new DialogFragment just ended up taking the whole screen. And as I though it was the Navigation way of showing the new fragment that was the culprit. The Navigation switches out the view you are in and replaces it with the destination view, thats just how Navigation works.

I did try using supportFragmentManager, but android studio doesn't want that. 
When you're in an activity you can use supportFragmentManager, but not in a fragment. When in a fragment already you use childFragmentManager. This did the trick and the new fragment behaves like a popup.

```
    val fm = childFragmentManager
    val someDetailDialogFragment = SomeDetailDialogFragment()

    // and some arg transfer
    val args = Bundle()
    args.putString("id", id)
    someDetailDialogFragment.arguments = args
    someDetailDialogFragment.show(fm, "Fragment_tag")
```